# Jade - Unexpected indentifier

Tags: pug

I'm getting the "Unexpected identifier" error whenever I try to compile Jade using Prepros.
This is my code:

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
    head
        title Hello World in Jade!
        style(href="style.css" rel="stylesheet")
```

Answer (score 4):

Attributes need to be separated by commas in jade.

```
style(href="style.css", rel="stylesheet")
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up to David's answer, the code you have in your example would be correct when implementing on Scalate (without commas).  When using the standard (JS) implementation of Jade, as he said, you separate attributes with commas.